# Variance of a slope estimator for a linear model

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

I am self-studying a textbook, and attempting an exercise in which the standard assumptions for a linear model apply, but not necessarily normality of the error term: $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_i]$ = 0, $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_i^2] = \sigma^2, \mathbb{E}[\epsilon_i \epsilon_j] = 0$ and $y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + \epsilon_i$. From this it follows that $var(y_i) = \sigma^2$.

In such a setting, we known the OLS estimator for the slope $\beta$ is equal to:

$$
b = \frac{\sum(x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2}
$$

and its variance is equal to:

$$
var(b) = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2}
$$

In the exercise, I am asked to calculate the variance of another (unbiased) estimator, $b_1 = \left( \frac{y_n - y_1}{x_n - x_1} \right)$, and show that the variance of this estimator $var(b_1) \geq var(b)$. The variance I calculated is:

$$
var(b_1) = var(\frac{y_n - y_1}{x_n - x_1}) = \frac{1}{(x_n - x_1)^2} var(y_n - y_1) = \frac{1}{(x_n - x_1)^2} [var(y_n) + var(y_1)] = \frac{2\sigma^2}{(x_n - x_1)^2}
$$

Is the variance that I calculated correct, and how do I show that this variance $var(b_1)$ is $\geq$ $var(b)$?

Many thanks for your help and assistance!

Comment: clearly $2\sigma \ge \sigma$ . what can you say about the denominators? What is the relation between $(x_n - x_1)^2$ and $\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2$  ?

Comment: Thank you very much for responding! This was the part I was struggling with, which led me to doubt I understood the concepts well enough to continue: $(x_n - x_1)^2$ is easily expanded as $x_n^2 -2x_1 x_n + x_1^2$, but $\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2$ does not easily simplify to something containing $x_1$ and $x_n$, so I didn't see how those two denominators compared..

Comment: but surely, $\bar{x} \le x_n$ and $x_1 \le \bar{x}$ so, what can you say about $\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2$

Comment: In this case, I definitely agree that it is easy to show that the denominator $(x_n - x_1)^2 = (x_n - \bar{x})^2 + (\bar{x} - x_1)^2 = (x_n - \bar{x})^2 + (x_1 - \bar{x})^2 \leq \sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2$. Hence, $\sigma \leq 2\sigma$, and $\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2 \geq (x_n - x_1)^2$, so $var(b) \leq var(b_1)$. But, this only holds if $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are ordered observations, and the book does not say that.. Thank you for your help anyway, I suppose I just need to assume that they are indeed ordered observations for it to be tractable.